# Why cant i reach the other network while i have added the routes and firewall rules to allow traffic? (Pfsense/USG200)

Tags: firewall, networking, pfsense, route

I have 2 networks, the current one and the new one. The current one is not configured by me and one big mess and contains heavily out dated hardware (especially servers). I want to be able to access the complete current network from the new one so i can migrate server for server and device for device.

Some network details:

- Current network:

  - IP: `192.168.1.1`
  - IP range: `192.168.104.0/24`
  - Router/firewall: Zyxel USG200
  - Contain all devices
  - Gives DHCP address to Pfsense (`192.168.104.4/24`)
- New network:

  - IP: `10.128.10.1`
  - IP range: `10.128.10.0/24`.
  - Router/firewall: Pfsense
  - Currently it contains only 1 device, my desktop but this network will replace the current one in future
  - All devices will be "moved" from the old to the new network by time (one for one)
  - Connected with old network by port with alias `"WAN 2"`

I added a route in each firewall to the other network.

- Zyxel: `10.128.10.0/24` via `192.168.104.4`
- Pfsense: `192.168.104.0/24` via `"WAN2"`

I also added a firewall rule to each firewall to `allow all traffic` from `all sources` to `all destinations` (for testing)

When i ping `192.168.104.1` with pfsense diagnostics, i got a response. I cannot find a way to do a ping from the Zyxel to Pfsense but as the route bellow is in the routing table i assume the (at least) routing configuration must be okay.

[image]

When i try to ping `192.168.104.1` (or any other device in the `104.x` network) from my desktop in the `10.128.10.x` network, i got a "request timed out" response. I also cannot SSH or browse to any IP in the `104.x` network.

When i connect my desktop to the `104.x` network and try to ping `10.128.10.1` or try to visit that IP in my browser (Pfsense web interface) i got "request timed out"

A print screen of my firewall rule on Pfsense (on the desktop interface):
[image]

And one from my firewall rule in the Zyxel:
[image]

**Probably i miss some configuration/settings but i have no idea what. Would be great when someone can help me out with this as i'm already struggling almost 2 days with this.** When extra details are required, let me know and i will update my question.

---

**UPDATE**

My config. I also obfuscated certs and private keys.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<pfsense>
    <version>19.1</version>
    <lastchange></lastchange>
    <system>
        <optimization>normal</optimization>
        <hostname>axx-psen-wal01</hostname>
        <domain>localdomain</domain>
        <group>
            <name>all</name>
            <description><![CDATA[All Users]]></description>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <gid>1998</gid>
            <member>0</member>
        </group>
        <group>
            <name>admins</name>
            <description><![CDATA[System Administrators]]></description>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <gid>1999</gid>
            <member>0</member>
            <priv>page-all</priv>
        </group>
        <user>
            <name>admin</name>
            <descr><![CDATA[System Administrator]]></descr>
            <scope>system</scope>
            <groupname>admins</groupname>
            <bcrypt-hash>***************************</bcrypt-hash>
            <uid>0</uid>
            <priv>user-shell-access</priv>
        </user>
        <nextuid>2000</nextuid>
        <nextgid>2000</nextgid>>
        <disablenatreflection>yes</disablenatreflection>
        <disablesegmentationoffloading></disablesegmentationoffloading>
        <disablelargereceiveoffloading></disablelargereceiveoffloading>
        <ipv6allow></ipv6allow>
        <maximumtableentries>400000</maximumtableentries>
        <powerd_ac_mode>hadp</powerd_ac_mode>
        <powerd_battery_mode>hadp</powerd_battery_mode>
        <powerd_normal_mode>hadp</powerd_normal_mode>
        <bogons>
            <interval>monthly</interval>
        </bogons>
        <already_run_config_upgrade></already_run_config_upgrade>
        <timezone>Europe/Amsterdam</timezone>
        <language>en_US</language>
        <dnsserver>8.8.8.8</dnsserver>
        <dnsallowoverride></dnsallowoverride>
        <dns1gw>none</dns1gw>
    </system>
    <interfaces>
        <wan>
            <enable></enable>
            <if>igb0</if>
            <blockpriv></blockpriv>
            <blockbogons></blockbogons>
            <descr><![CDATA[WAN1]]></descr>
            <ipaddr>dhcp</ipaddr>
            <dhcphostname></dhcphostname>
            <alias-address></alias-address>
            <alias-subnet>32</alias-subnet>
            <dhcprejectfrom></dhcprejectfrom>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_timeout></adv_dhcp_pt_timeout>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_retry></adv_dhcp_pt_retry>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_select_timeout></adv_dhcp_pt_select_timeout>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_reboot></adv_dhcp_pt_reboot>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_backoff_cutoff></adv_dhcp_pt_backoff_cutoff>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_initial_interval></adv_dhcp_pt_initial_interval>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_values>SavedCfg</adv_dhcp_pt_values>
            <adv_dhcp_send_options></adv_dhcp_send_options>
            <adv_dhcp_request_options></adv_dhcp_request_options>
            <adv_dhcp_required_options></adv_dhcp_required_options>
            <adv_dhcp_option_modifiers></adv_dhcp_option_modifiers>
            <adv_dhcp_config_advanced></adv_dhcp_config_advanced>
            <adv_dhcp_config_file_override></adv_dhcp_config_file_override>
            <adv_dhcp_config_file_override_path></adv_dhcp_config_file_override_path>
            <ipaddrv6>dhcp6</ipaddrv6>
            <dhcp6-duid></dhcp6-duid>
            <dhcp6-ia-pd-len>0</dhcp6-ia-pd-len>
            <adv_dhcp6_prefix_selected_interface>wan</adv_dhcp6_prefix_selected_interface>
            <spoofmac></spoofmac>
        </wan>
        <lan>
            <enable></enable>
            <if>igb1</if>
            <descr><![CDATA[WAN2]]></descr>
            <spoofmac>c1:9b:43:75:5a:65</spoofmac>
            <ipaddr>dhcp</ipaddr>
            <dhcphostname></dhcphostname>
            <alias-address></alias-address>
            <alias-subnet>32</alias-subnet>
            <dhcprejectfrom></dhcprejectfrom>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_timeout></adv_dhcp_pt_timeout>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_retry></adv_dhcp_pt_retry>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_select_timeout></adv_dhcp_pt_select_timeout>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_reboot></adv_dhcp_pt_reboot>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_backoff_cutoff></adv_dhcp_pt_backoff_cutoff>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_initial_interval></adv_dhcp_pt_initial_interval>
            <adv_dhcp_pt_values>SavedCfg</adv_dhcp_pt_values>
            <adv_dhcp_send_options></adv_dhcp_send_options>
            <adv_dhcp_request_options></adv_dhcp_request_options>
            <adv_dhcp_required_options></adv_dhcp_required_options>
            <adv_dhcp_option_modifiers></adv_dhcp_option_modifiers>
            <adv_dhcp_config_advanced></adv_dhcp_config_advanced>
            <adv_dhcp_config_file_override></adv_dhcp_config_file_override>
            <adv_dhcp_config_file_override_path></adv_dhcp_config_file_override_path>
            <ipaddrv6>track6</ipaddrv6>
            <track6-interface>wan</track6-interface>
            <track6-prefix-id>0</track6-prefix-id>
        </lan>
        <opt1>
            <descr><![CDATA[LAN1]]></descr>
            <if>igb2</if>
            <enable></enable>
            <spoofmac></spoofmac>
        </opt1>
        <opt2>
            <descr><![CDATA[LAN2]]></descr>
            <if>igb3</if>
            <enable></enable>
            <ipaddr>192.168.200.1</ipaddr>
            <subnet>24</subnet>
            <spoofmac></spoofmac>
        </opt2>
        <opt3>
            <descr><![CDATA[axn_mgmt]]></descr>
            <if>igb2.5</if>
            <enable></enable>
            <spoofmac></spoofmac>
        </opt3>
        <opt4>
            <descr><![CDATA[axn_intra]]></descr>
            <if>igb2.10</if>
            <enable></enable>
            <ipaddr>10.128.10.1</ipaddr>
            <subnet>24</subnet>
            <spoofmac></spoofmac>
        </opt4>
    </interfaces>
    <staticroutes>
        <route>
            <network>192.168.104.0/24</network>
            <gateway>WAN2_DHCP</gateway>
            <descr><![CDATA[Zyxel compatibility rule]]></descr>
        </route>
    </staticroutes>
    <dhcpd>
        <lan>
            <range>
                <from>192.168.1.10</from>
                <to>192.168.1.245</to>
            </range>
            <dhcpleaseinlocaltime></dhcpleaseinlocaltime>
            <failover_peerip></failover_peerip>
            <defaultleasetime></defaultleasetime>
            <maxleasetime></maxleasetime>
            <netmask></netmask>
            <gateway></gateway>
            <domain></domain>
            <domainsearchlist></domainsearchlist>
            <ddnsdomain></ddnsdomain>
            <ddnsdomainprimary></ddnsdomainprimary>
            <ddnsdomainkeyname></ddnsdomainkeyname>
            <ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>hmac-md5</ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>
            <ddnsdomainkey></ddnsdomainkey>
            <mac_allow></mac_allow>
            <mac_deny></mac_deny>
            <ddnsclientupdates>allow</ddnsclientupdates>
            <tftp></tftp>
            <ldap></ldap>
            <nextserver></nextserver>
            <filename></filename>
            <filename32></filename32>
            <filename64></filename64>
            <rootpath></rootpath>
            <numberoptions></numberoptions>
        </lan>
        <opt2>
            <range>
                <from>192.168.200.30</from>
                <to>192.168.200.199</to>
            </range>
            <failover_peerip></failover_peerip>
            <defaultleasetime></defaultleasetime>
            <maxleasetime></maxleasetime>
            <netmask></netmask>
            <gateway></gateway>
            <domain></domain>
            <domainsearchlist></domainsearchlist>
            <ddnsdomain></ddnsdomain>
            <ddnsdomainprimary></ddnsdomainprimary>
            <ddnsdomainkeyname></ddnsdomainkeyname>
            <ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>hmac-md5</ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>
            <ddnsdomainkey></ddnsdomainkey>
            <mac_allow></mac_allow>
            <mac_deny></mac_deny>
            <ddnsclientupdates>allow</ddnsclientupdates>
            <tftp></tftp>
            <ldap></ldap>
            <nextserver></nextserver>
            <filename></filename>
            <filename32></filename32>
            <filename64></filename64>
            <rootpath></rootpath>
            <numberoptions></numberoptions>
            <enable></enable>
            <dhcpleaseinlocaltime></dhcpleaseinlocaltime>
        </opt2>
        <opt4>
            <range>
                <from>10.128.10.30</from>
                <to>10.128.10.199</to>
            </range>
            <enable></enable>
            <failover_peerip></failover_peerip>
            <defaultleasetime></defaultleasetime>
            <maxleasetime></maxleasetime>
            <netmask></netmask>
            <gateway></gateway>
            <domain></domain>
            <domainsearchlist></domainsearchlist>
            <ddnsdomain></ddnsdomain>
            <ddnsdomainprimary></ddnsdomainprimary>
            <ddnsdomainkeyname></ddnsdomainkeyname>
            <ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>hmac-md5</ddnsdomainkeyalgorithm>
            <ddnsdomainkey></ddnsdomainkey>
            <mac_allow></mac_allow>
            <mac_deny></mac_deny>
            <ddnsclientupdates>allow</ddnsclientupdates>
            <tftp></tftp>
            <ldap></ldap>
            <nextserver></nextserver>
            <filename></filename>
            <filename32></filename32>
            <filename64></filename64>
            <rootpath></rootpath>
            <numberoptions></numberoptions>
            <dhcpleaseinlocaltime></dhcpleaseinlocaltime>
            <dnsserver>8.8.8.8</dnsserver>
        </opt4>
    </dhcpd>
    <dhcpdv6>
        <lan>
            <enable></enable>
            <range>
                <from>::1000</from>
                <to>::2000</to>
            </range>
            <ramode>assist</ramode>
            <rapriority>medium</rapriority>
        </lan>
    </dhcpdv6>
    <snmpd>
        <syslocation></syslocation>
        <syscontact></syscontact>
        <rocommunity>public</rocommunity>
    </snmpd>
    <diag>
        <ipv6nat>
            <ipaddr></ipaddr>
        </ipv6nat>
    </diag>
    <syslog>
        <filterdescriptions>1</filterdescriptions>
    </syslog>
    <nat>
        <outbound>
            <mode>automatic</mode>
        </outbound>
    </nat>
    <filter>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589535222</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>lan</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <source>
                <any></any>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <any></any>
            </destination>
            <disabled></disabled>
            <descr><![CDATA[test rule]]></descr>
            <created>
                <time>1589535222</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
            <updated>
                <time>1589537043</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589534465</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>opt2</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <source>
                <any></any>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <any></any>
            </destination>
            <descr></descr>
            <updated>
                <time>1589534465</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.100 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
            <created>
                <time>1589534465</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.1.100 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589536898</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>opt4</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <protocol>icmp</protocol>
            <icmptype>any</icmptype>
            <source>
                <any></any>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <any></any>
            </destination>
            <descr><![CDATA[test rule]]></descr>
            <created>
                <time>1589536898</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
            <updated>
                <time>1589537026</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589535642</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>opt4</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <source>
                <any></any>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <any></any>
            </destination>
            <descr><![CDATA[test rule]]></descr>
            <created>
                <time>1589535642</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
            <updated>
                <time>1589537018</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589535105</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>opt4</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <source>
                <network>opt4</network>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <address>192.168.104.0/24</address>
            </destination>
            <descr><![CDATA[Zyxel compatibility rule]]></descr>
            <created>
                <time>1589535105</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
            <updated>
                <time>1589536984</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589535574</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>opt4</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <source>
                <network>opt4</network>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <any></any>
            </destination>
            <descr><![CDATA[axn_mgmt to all rule]]></descr>
            <created>
                <time>1589535574</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
            <updated>
                <time>1589537000</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
        </rule>
        <rule>
            <id></id>
            <tracker>1589534846</tracker>
            <type>pass</type>
            <interface>opt4</interface>
            <ipprotocol>inet</ipprotocol>
            <tag></tag>
            <tagged></tagged>
            <max></max>
            <max-src-nodes></max-src-nodes>
            <max-src-conn></max-src-conn>
            <max-src-states></max-src-states>
            <statetimeout></statetimeout>
            <statetype><![CDATA[keep state]]></statetype>
            <os></os>
            <source>
                <network>opt4</network>
            </source>
            <destination>
                <network>opt4ip</network>
            </destination>
            <descr><![CDATA[axn_intra to axn_intra]]></descr>
            <created>
                <time>1589534846</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@192.168.200.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </created>
            <updated>
                <time>1589536973</time>
                <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
            </updated>
        </rule>
        <separator>
            <opt2></opt2>
            <opt4></opt4>
            <lan></lan>
            <wan></wan>
        </separator>
    </filter>
    <shaper></shaper>
    <ipsec></ipsec>
    <aliases></aliases>
    <proxyarp></proxyarp>
    <cron>
        <item>
            <minute>1,31</minute>
            <hour>0-5</hour>
            <mday>*</mday>
            <month>*</month>
            <wday>*</wday>
            <who>root</who>
            <command>/usr/bin/nice -n20 adjkerntz -a</command>
        </item>
        <item>
            <minute>1</minute>
            <hour>3</hour>
            <mday>1</mday>
            <month>*</month>
            <wday>*</wday>
            <who>root</who>
            <command>/usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.update_bogons.sh</command>
        </item>
        <item>
            <minute>1</minute>
            <hour>1</hour>
            <mday>*</mday>
            <month>*</month>
            <wday>*</wday>
            <who>root</who>
            <command>/usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.dyndns.update</command>
        </item>
        <item>
            <minute>*/60</minute>
            <hour>*</hour>
            <mday>*</mday>
            <month>*</month>
            <wday>*</wday>
            <who>root</who>
            <command>/usr/bin/nice -n20 /usr/local/sbin/expiretable -v -t 3600 virusprot</command>
        </item>
        <item>
            <minute>30</minute>
            <hour>12</hour>
            <mday>*</mday>
            <month>*</month>
            <wday>*</wday>
            <who>root</who>
            <command>/usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.update_urltables</command>
        </item>
        <item>
            <minute>1</minute>
            <hour>0</hour>
            <mday>*</mday>
            <month>*</month>
            <wday>*</wday>
            <who>root</who>
            <command>/usr/bin/nice -n20 /etc/rc.update_pkg_metadata</command>
        </item>
    </cron>
    <wol></wol>
    <rrd>
        <enable></enable>
    </rrd>
    <load_balancer>
        <monitor_type>
            <name>ICMP</name>
            <type>icmp</type>
            <descr><![CDATA[ICMP]]></descr>
            <options></options>
        </monitor_type>
        <monitor_type>
            <name>TCP</name>
            <type>tcp</type>
            <descr><![CDATA[Generic TCP]]></descr>
            <options></options>
        </monitor_type>
        <monitor_type>
            <name>HTTP</name>
            <type>http</type>
            <descr><![CDATA[Generic HTTP]]></descr>
            <options>
                <path>/</path>
                <host></host>
                <code>200</code>
            </options>
        </monitor_type>
        <monitor_type>
            <name>HTTPS</name>
            <type>https</type>
            <descr><![CDATA[Generic HTTPS]]></descr>
            <options>
                <path>/</path>
                <host></host>
                <code>200</code>
            </options>
        </monitor_type>
        <monitor_type>
            <name>SMTP</name>
            <type>send</type>
            <descr><![CDATA[Generic SMTP]]></descr>
            <options>
                <send></send>
                <expect>220 *</expect>
            </options>
        </monitor_type>
    </load_balancer>
    <widgets>
        <sequence>system_information:col1:open:0,interfaces:col2:open:0,netgate_services_and_support:col2:open:0</sequence>
        <period>10</period>
    </widgets>
    <openvpn></openvpn>
    <dnshaper></dnshaper>
    <unbound>
        <enable></enable>
        <dnssec></dnssec>
        <active_interface></active_interface>
        <outgoing_interface></outgoing_interface>
        <custom_options></custom_options>
        <hideidentity></hideidentity>
        <hideversion></hideversion>
        <dnssecstripped></dnssecstripped>
    </unbound>
    <revision>
        <time>1589537382</time>
        <description><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database): Firewall: Rules - deleted a firewall rule.]]></description>
        <username><![CDATA[admin@10.128.10.30 (Local Database)]]></username>
    </revision>
    <cert>
        <refid>5ebe5df4744c4</refid>
        <descr><![CDATA[webConfigurator default (5ebe5df4744c4)]]></descr>
        <type>server</type>
        <crt>********************==</crt>
        <prv>********************==</prv>
    </cert>
    <ppps></ppps>
    <gateways>
        <defaultgw4>WAN1_DHCP</defaultgw4>
        <defaultgw6></defaultgw6>
    </gateways>
    <vlans>
        <vlan>
            <if>igb2</if>
            <tag>5</tag>
            <pcp></pcp>
            <descr><![CDATA[axn_mgmt]]></descr>
            <vlanif>igb2.5</vlanif>
        </vlan>
        <vlan>
            <if>igb2</if>
            <tag>10</tag>
            <pcp></pcp>
            <descr><![CDATA[axn_intra]]></descr>
            <vlanif>igb2.10</vlanif>
        </vlan>
    </vlans>
</pfsense>
```

---

**UPDATE 2**

The diagram bellow should help to understand my situation.
[image]

Comment: `tracert` is a thing...

Comment: When i `tracert 192.168.104.1` from my desktop (connected to `10.128.10.x`) i cannot come further than 1 step `10.128.10.1` ---  When i `tracert 10.128.10.1` from my desktop (when connected to `192.168.104.x`) i cannot come further than 1 step `192.168.104.1`  --- in both cases i expected 2 steps?

Comment: pfsense will log dropped packets.  Look there first.

Comment: The only relevant things i can find is: `14:55:34.888604 IP 192.168.104.4 > 192.168.104.1: ICMP echo request, id 9474, seq 15844, length 8
-- 14:55:34.889239 IP 192.168.104.1 > 192.168.104.4: ICMP echo reply, id 9474, seq 15844, length 8`

Comment: Please include the text version of your configuration. Simply list it out and paste it into the question using the Preformatted-text feaute (`{}`). You should obfuscate any passwords and public addresses.

Comment: @RonMaupin i updated my question. Hope you have enough details now to help me out.

Comment: I started re-configuring Pfsense from scratch (factory defaults) to be sure that i did not a mess up any configuration during my testing and experimenting to get it work. --- I updated the question so it contains a *complete*  export of my config now. Hope this will help .... I have no idea how of where to continue...

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Comment: No, none of the answers helped me. We decided to do a "big bang". We replaced the USG by pfSense as we could get it done to run both (the old and the new) networks parallel.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As we where not able to solve the issue, we decided to do a "big bang". We connected all devices from the old network one by one to the new network as we could not get it done to run both (the old and the new) networks parallel.

This made the transition not as smooth as we hoped we could do but we saw no other option.

Comment: Please accept your answer so that the question does not keep popping up forever, looking for an answer.

Answer (score 1):

Your config has `<blockpriv/>` which (I believe) will NOT allow requests **OUT** to `192.168.104.0` via WAN... and will NOT allow requests **IN** to `10.128.10.0`.

I would also check for a similar setting in the other router... as ALL brands (in theory) BLOCK local addresses on WAN by default.

> Otherwise, a nefarious party could externally advertise 192.168.0.1 as being on their network... some sloppy AT&T routers somewhere would likely pick that up and suddenly the hacker is getting inbound traffic from unsuspecting hard-coded ioT devices etc.

Answer (score 0):

All IP Sub-nets connected with a specific Interface should be able able to reach there Next-Hop or Firewall Interface or Gateway First.

Can you confirm whether while connecting your system in New Series, you are able to reach your next hop IP that is the IP Of Firewall Interface in this case ?

Comment: @K K Satapathy I updated my question so you can see what i can ping and what not. --- I can only hop 1 step. Means from pc1 to its gateway, from pc2 to its gateway, from Pfsense to Zyxel --- cannot ping directly from pc2 to Zyxel

Answer (score 0):

Configuration Looks fine as per Diagram shared. However you can check whether you have enabled nating in Firewall Routes for the Local Policy. If so disable Nating in the Firewall Policy.

Check Firewall Setting in your Computer & Turn it Off.

You May Try with Specific Policies containing Source & Destination IP Series .

Comment: I have no NAT rules configured at Pfsense except for the outbound rules. (see my config export added to the question) -- At the Zyxel i did not change any NAT rules after i started with this implementation. There are no "automatic" NAT rules active there.-- temp disable all NAT rules at Pfsense does also not work, i can't do this on the Zyxel as this network is operational.

Comment: I already had my local (computer) firewall disabled which didn't help. Hope you have any other suggestions i can try? -- i started configuring pfsense from scratch to be sure i didn't mess up a setting accidentally. -- a *complete* most recent config can be found in my question